# Passport.js -- inserts 'null' into database instead of username

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, express, passport.js

Having trouble creating a user with an Id, username, and password field. It says insertId is not defined, however, when I unquote the quoted code in the below code, it sort of works, except it puts "null" as the username in the database and correctly redirects me to the profile page. Any ideas?

```
var LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;

var mysql = require('mysql');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var dbconfig = require('./database');
var connection = mysql.createConnection(dbconfig.connection);

connection.query('USE ' + dbconfig.database);

module.exports = function(passport) {
 passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
  done(null, user.id);
 });

 passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
  connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ? ", [id],
   function(err, rows){
    done(err, rows[0]);
   });
 });

 passport.use(
  'local-signup',
  new LocalStrategy({
   usernameField : 'username',
   passwordField: 'password',
   passReqToCallback: true
  },
  function(req, username, password, done){
   connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? ", 
   [username], function(err, rows){
    if(err)
     return done(err);
    if(rows.length){
     return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That is already taken'));
    }else{
     var newUserMysql = {
      username: username,
      password: bcrypt.hashSync(password, null, null),
     };

     var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) values (?, ?)";

     connection.query(insertQuery, [/*newUserMysql.id,*/ newUserMysql.username, newUserMysql.password],
      function(err, rows){
       newUserMysql.id = insertId;

       return done(null, newUserMysql);
      });
    }
   });
  })
 );

 passport.use(
  'local-login',
  new LocalStrategy({
   usernameField : 'username',
   passwordField: 'password',
   passReqToCallback: true
  },
  function(req, username, password, done){
   connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? ", [username],
   function(err, rows){
    if(err)
     return done(err);
    if(!rows.length){
     return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No User Found'));
    }
    if(!bcrypt.compareSync(password, rows[0].password))
     return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Wrong Password'));

    return done(null, rows[0]);
   });
  })
 );
};
```

Any suggestions/comments would be greatly appreciated. I've tried adding an Id field to newUserMySql variables but it just buggers it up even more.

Edit: Suddenly, even when I uncomment out the code, the error says insertid is not defined, and it turns off the server. Seems to compile differently everytime I run it.